# Multiple Domains on single grails application and second domain only with access to one specific controller?

Tags: spring, grails, grails-orm, grails-plugin

I have a grails 2.2.2 application and i want to have two domains connected with it.
Domain.tld and shop.domain.tld.

Requests over domain.tld aren't allowed to access to ShopController. Only shop.domain.tld should have access to ShopController, but to no other Controller of the application.

I also want to use the grails url-rewriting. Is there a possibility to implement such use-case with grails? If yes, how would you implement it?

In the end i want that for example each online shop can be accessed by
shop.domain.tld/ID

and not by domain.tld/shop/myShop/ID. domain.tld is supposed to other purposes.

Thanks and best regards

Comment: you can point your DNS to same IP address where your grails app is located.  you can also use nginx or apache in from of tomcat. see my simple sample http://javadeveloper.asia/configuring-nginx-in-front-of-tomcat-or-other-java-application-server.  you can access which domain you are in, in your controller and code accordingly

Answer (score 0):

If both domain points to the same server, and Tomcat is used for both as your public facing web server, then you just need to modify the part inside your Grails.

In Controller, you can check which domain was used to access your application:

```
def uri = new java.net.URI(request.getHeader("referer"))
def domainName = uri.getHost()
```